# Carousel de Bootstrap dinámico con PHP

Tags: php, bootstrap

Buen dia! Quisiera crear un carousel con los estilos de Bootstrap pero que, en lugar de poner las imágines predeterminadas, las vaya sacando de un directorio.
Las imagenes se muestran pero en bloque, no como slider. 
Quisiera saber si pueden ayudarme a encontrar el error. 
Gracias de antemano!
Primero creo un array con las url de las imágenes desde el directorio.

```
<?php
  $aImagenes = array();
  $path= "images/widget-slider-home/slides/";
  $directorio=dir($path);
  $iCont = 1;
  while ($archivo = $directorio->read())
  {
      if ($archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.')
      {
        $aImagenes[$iCont] = $archivo;
        $iCont++;
       }
   }
  $directorio->close();
   ?>
```

Creo el carousel

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <!-- Indicators -->
```

Coloco el primer item como item activo y el resto solo item y luego va avanzando (la proxima imagen seria activa, y asi sucesivamente)

```
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
```

';
   } else {
       echo '';
   }
} ?>

Le indico la url de la imagen que tiene que ir mostrando segun sea o no active

```
 <div class="carousel-inner" roles="listbox">
  <?php for($i=0;$i<count($aImagenes); $i++)
  {
    ?>
    <div class="item <?php if($i==0) {echo 'active';}?>">
      <?php foreach ($aImagenes as $iImg => $sNombre)
      {
          ?><img src="<?=$path;?><?=$sNombre;?>" alt="<?=$sNombre;?>" style="width:100%;"/><?php
      }
      ?>
    </div>
    <?php
   }
   ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esto hace que, como les dije, se vean todas las imagenes (es decir que la url de la imagen la toma bien, por lo cual la funcion que trae imagenes del directorio esta correcta, y la fotma de traerlos con el carousel, tambien) Una encima de la otra.
Desde ya, muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: tu mismo te respondiste, en el slider si todas aparecen como activas pierde la función y las muestra todas al mismo tiempo.

Comment: No entiendo el error, ¿puedes plantear la pregunta de otra forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que te está sobrando el `foreach`, resultando en que todas las fotos aparezcan dentro del mismo item:

Quitándolo, con el ciclo `for` recorrés el array, y por cada una generás un `<div class="item">` con la imagen dentro:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" roles="listbox">

    <?php for($i=0; $i < count($aImagenes); $i++) { ?>

    <div class="item <?php if ($i==0) { echo 'active'; }?>">

        <img src="<?=$path;?><?=$aImagenes[$i];?>" alt="<?=$aImagenes[$i];?>" style="width:100%;"/>

    </div>

    <?php } ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Me funcionó a la perfección!

Comment: Buenísimo, me alegro! :D